# Check for broken links behind a login wall

Tags: software-testing, hyperlink

I am looking for a tool similar to [W3C's link checker](https://validator.w3.org/checklink) that will display any broken links BEHIND A LOGIN WALL.

Currently, I login and open Chrome's developer console to inspect the errors. This is both tedious and error prone. I would love to pass some credentials to a service and have it crawl the site regularly.

Does anyone know of such a service? My initial use will be to scan for broken image links on an internal company storefront.

Comment: It has to be a hosted Web app, or would a desktop client or a self-hosted Web app be okay, too?

Answer (score 1):

First a cautionary word you should ideally ask the site admin for a user name and password for a test user so as not to require the use of your own username & password in the test scripts.  Alternatively, if the site allows registration you should register a test username, password & email.

Once you have done that you can set up walking the site and checking the links using [python](http://python.org) and either [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or possibly [Requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/2.7.0).  Both can handle working on sites that require logging in.

I would recommend prompting the user for the username and password, (once), and storing them in environment variables for the duration of the session might be a good security practice.

## Examples of scraping a site that requires a login

### Scrapy

*From the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html?highlight=password#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login).*

```
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

### Requests

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
# You now need to check for a successful login and start to walk the site checking the links.
```

The other cautionary is that some sites rely heavily on JavaScript to (re-)generate links - in this case you will need to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), to generate then parse those links.

Comment: Java !== Javascript